# In GoF Observer Pattern, why are the methods in derived class virtual?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, observer-pattern

In GoF observer pattern, the `subject` is

```
class Subject {
  public:
    virtual ~Subject();
    virtual void Attach(Observer*);
    virtual void Detach(Observer*);
    virtual void Notify();
  protected:
    Subject();
  private:
    List<Observer*> *_observers;
};
```

and the concrete subject `ClockTimer` is given as

```
class ClockTimer : public Subject {
  public:
    ClockTimer();
    virtual int GetHour();
    virtual int GetMinute();
    virtual int GetSecond();
    void Tick();
};
```

I understand `Subject` is abstract therefore all methods are `virtual`. But why are the methods of `ClockTimer` virtual? It's not an abstract class after all.

Comment: You can't override non-virtual methods. The GoF book leans heavily into Smalltalk or Java flavour of OOP, where (nearly) every method is overridable.

Comment: But why in the derived class? Is this to allow deriving `ClockTimer`, if that may be needed?

Comment: Sure. A `WallClockTimer` or `SystemClockTimer` might be what they had in mind. It's been awhile since I read the book.

Answer (score 1):

As [cppreference says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual):

> Virtual functions are member functions **whose behavior can be
> overridden in derived classes**. As opposed to non-virtual functions,
> the overriding behavior is preserved even if there is no compile-time
> information about the actual type of the class. That is to say, if a
> derived class is handled using pointer or reference to the base class,
> a call to an overridden virtual function would invoke the behavior
> defined in the derived class. Such a function call is known as virtual
> function call or virtual call.

So GoF has used virtual functions to override behaviour in derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

The only method that must be virtual in the Observer pattern is `Observer::update`.    In the following code, `SubjectBase` can correctly be used as a base class for a concrete subject (e.g. `ClockTimer`) since the constructor and destructor are protected.  The "state" methods of the concrete subject (e.g. `GetHour`) do not need to be virtual.

Since `SubjectBase` is non-virtual, the `final` specifier cannot be used.  This allows derived classes to define different behavior for the fundamental methods (i.e. `attach`, `detach`, and `notify`).  Unless there are pressing performance considerations, it is preferable to implement `Subject` as a polymorphic class.  Lastly, I see no fundamental reason to define the constructor as protected when `Subject` is a polymorphic class.

```
#include <list>

class Observer {
public:
    virtual ~Observer() = default;
    virtual void update() = 0;
};

class ConcreteObserver : public Observer {
public:
    void update() override;
};

class SubjectBase {
public:
    void attach(Observer* o);
    void detach(Observer* o);
    void notify();

protected:
    SubjectBase() = default;
    ~SubjectBase() = default;
private:
    std::list<Observer*> m_observers;
};

class Subject {
public:
    Subject() = default;
    virtual ~Subject() = default;
    virtual void attach(Observer* o) final;
    virtual void detach(Observer* o) final;
    virtual void notify() final;

private:
    std::list<Observer*> m_observers;
};

class ConcreteSubject : public Subject {
public:
    struct State;
    State getState();
    void attach(Observer* o); // compile time error!
};
```

Comment: @Thanks, for my clarification, did you by accident include both `Subject` and `SubjectBase` in your code example?

Comment: @TMOTTM, ConcreteSubject can derive from either Subject or SubjectBase (don't inherit from both).  I included them both intentionally...although, I probably should have created two separate code blocks for clarity.